# Jquery Sum by Group from Table/Input Data

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-events

I'm looking to Group my Table data and Sum by the group (like sum price by product). In a second Table.

I want group or filter by Item column, and sum the result of the Price column.

So Oranges (having two lines) should be one line with Sum price.

See this example below:

```
    <table width="400" border="1">
      <tr>
        <td>Item</td>
        <td>Location</td>
        <td>Quantity</td>
        <td>Price</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input name="item" type="text" id="item" value="Orange" /></td>
        <td><input name="location" type="text" id="location" value="Tree" /></td>
        <td><input name="quantity" type="text" id="quantity" value="3" /></td>
        <td><input name="price" type="text" id="price" value="3.00" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input name="item" type="text" id="item2" value="Apple" /></td>
        <td><input name="location" type="text" id="location" value="Tree" /></td>
        <td><input name="quantity" type="text" id="quantity" value="1" /></td>
        <td><input name="price" type="text" id="price" value="1.00" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input name="item" type="text" id="item" value="Orange" /></td>
        <td><input name="location" type="text" id="location" value="Tree" /></td>
        <td><input name="quantity" type="text" id="quantity" value="4" /></td>
        <td><input name="price" type="text" id="price" value="4.00" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input name="item" type="text" id="item" value="Grapes" /></td>
        <td><input name="location" type="text" id="location" value="Vine" /></td>
        <td><input name="quantity" type="text" id="quantity" value="10" /></td>
        <td><input name="price" type="text" id="price" value="10.00" /></td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <table width="400" border="1">
      <tr>
        <td>Orange</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>7.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Apple</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Grapes</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>10.00</td>
      </tr>  
    </table>
```

Comment: first, id must unique through out the page... change it to class...

Comment: Thanks, classes have help to group by name...but I can't figure to add the price for that group...thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

First change id "price" to class, then

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var sum = 0;
   $('.price').each(function(){
       sum += $(this).val();
   });
   alert("The sum is " + sum);
});
```

You can modify above code to get sum in button click event too.

Comment: This looks good for a total column sum but how does it select/group/filter by item? Seems like this work in a loop if I new the product the price was associated to??  Agin I'm new...